# Confirm selection among options

Tags: autocompletion

When searching for autocompletion on any command via <kbd>Tab</kbd>, now `vim` shows me a list of the available options:

[image]

I was used to push the right-arrow <kbd>-></kbd> in order to select an option while navigating them with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but now that doesn't work anymore. I need to push the <kbd>Space</kbd> button instead, but that's pretty annoying when going inside a file-system hierarchy as I need to delete every white space again to show the new listing of files.

Is there a way to restore the <kbd>-></kbd> selector?

Comment: Do you have `set wildmenu` in your vimrc? If you don't, adding it should resolve your problem.

Comment: @statox That's it, thanks! However the wild menu shall be removed to go back to the previous default behaviour: `set nowildmenu`. If you wish to answer with this, you can proceed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is controlled by the `wildmenu` option ([`:h 'wildmenu'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wildmenu%27))

> While the "wildmenu" is active the following keys have special
>   meanings:
>
> `<Left> <Right>`  - select previous/next match (like CTRL-P/CTRL-N)
>
> `<Down>`      - in filename/menu name completion: move into a subdirectory or submenu.
>
> `<CR>`        - in menu completion, when the cursor is just after a dot: move into a submenu.
>
> `<Up>`        - in filename/menu name completion: move up into parent directory or parent menu.

The default value of this option is off but I would say that it is useful to add `set wildmenu` to your vimrc.

Comment: Great, thank you! Ah... then with the `wildmenu` I can still use the `<Down>` arrow to select the item.. awesome